# Why does not work select from a keyed table

Tags: kdb, k

A query result looks good if I break keyed table apart into key-value pair and combine them together: `key!value`. But a straight select from it gives an error. I constructed that keyed table in a slightly weird manner:

```
q)show t:([n:1 2] m:(`a`b!3 4;`a`b!5 6));
n| m
-| --------
1| `a`b!3 4
2| `a`b!5 6
q)t[;`m]
n| a b
-| ---
1| 3 4
2| 5 6
q)select from (key t[;`m])!value t[;`m]
n| a b
-| ---
1| 3 4
2| 5 6
q)select from t[;`m]
'type
  [0]  select from t[;`m]
       ^
```

Where does this `'type` error come from?

Answer (score 3):

Doing an exact match on what we expect `` t[;`m] `` to be shows that something is up. If we deconstruct and reconstruct we get them being equal.

```
q)([n:1 2]a:3 5;b:4 6)~t[;`m]
0b
q)([n:1 2]a:3 5;b:4 6)~{key[x]!value x}t[;`m]
1b
```

We can get clues from the internal byte representation using `-8!`, which unfortunately is not well documented. It seems that the values are being represented as a general list (type 0h => `0x00`) of dictionaries instead of a table (type 98h => `0x62`).

```
q)-8!`a`b!3 4
0x0100000029000000630b00020000006100620007000200000003000000000000000400000000000000
q)-8!t[;`m]
0x0100000078000000636200630b00010000006e0000000100000007000200000001000000000000000200000000000000000002000000630b00020000006100620007000200000003000000000000000400000000000000630b00020000006100620007000200000005000000000000000600000000000000
q)-8!([n:1 2]a:3 5;b:4 6)
0x010000006f000000636200630b00010000006e00000001000000070002000000010000000000000002000000000000006200630b0002000000610062000000020000000700020000000300000000000000050000000000000007000200000004000000000000000600000000000000
```